# upickling error data was truncated - better way to save large dataframe

Tags: python, pickle

I have a quite a large dataframe that I need to save. The size is approx 300mb when I save it using pickle.

I read about some other ways of saving large dataframes. I am using bz2.BZ2File & I can see the file is now only 50mb. However when I try to load the data I get the following error,

> UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

Is there a better way for saving a large dataframe?

Comment: Did you try saving it as an csv? Although write times are slightly slow, it is pretty okay. Afterwards the csv could be zipped.

Comment: thanks that works nicely. If you write your answer as a comment I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the dataframe as a csv file can help. A dataframe contains more information than solely the data, so when pickling, such dataframe is converted to a string which takes up a lot of space which a csv would not.

Notice that the method `to_csv` even supports compression. E.g. to save as a zip:

```
df.to_csv('filename.zip', compression='infer')
```